# Salesforce CLI destructive changes (sfdx sgd:source:delta) not showing difference in branches using GItHub Actions

Tags: salesforce, github-actions, salesforce-cli, sfdx

I am using the Salesforce destructive changes mentioned [here](https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta). However, sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" --from "HEAD^" --output . --generate-delta command is not showing any destructive changes, it generates a destructiveChanges.xml without any deleted metadata.

```
--- destructiveChanges.xml generated with deleted metadata ---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

Here is the content of the yml file I am using:

```
name: sf-destructivechanges

on:

  push:

    branches:

      - "test"

jobs:

 sf-destructivechanges:

   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

   steps:

     - uses: actions/checkout@v2

     - name: Install Salesforce CLI

       run: |

           wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz

           mkdir sfdx-cli

           tar xJf sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz -C sfdx-cli --strip-components 1

           ./sfdx-cli/install

           sfdx update

     - name: Install plugin

       run: | 

           echo 'y' | sfdx plugins:install sfdx-git-delta

     - name: Get delta files with SGD

       run: sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" --from "HEAD^" --output . --generate-delta

     - name: Deploy changes

       run: |

           echo "--- package.xml generated with added and modified metadata ---"

           cat package/package.xml

           echo

           echo "---- Deploying added and modified metadata ----"

           sfdx force:source:deploy -x package/package.xml -u ${{ secrets.USERNAME}}

     - name: Destructive Changes

       run: |

           echo "--- destructiveChanges.xml generated with deleted metadata ---"

           cat destructiveChanges/destructiveChanges.xml

           echo

           echo "--- Deleting removed metadata ---"

           sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d destructiveChanges  -u ${{ secrets.USERNAME}} -w -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and I believe its related to

```
(node:94996) Warning: Deprecated config name: apiVersion. Please use org-api-version instead.
```

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
{
"error": null,
"output": ".",
"success": true,
"warnings": []
}